# Why can I use the random.radint method without instantiating an instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

To use the random.randint method I can use the following two options:

```
import random

# one way to use random
random.randint(1,10)

# second way with instanciating first
instance = random.Random()
instance.randint(1,10)
```

Why can I use the first way although I did not instantiate an instance yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing `random` instantiates `Random` into a private variable.

On line 786 of `random.py`.

```
_inst = Random()
```

And then on line 791.

```
randint = _inst.randint
```

`random.py` resides in the `Lib` folder of your python installation if you want to check it out yourself.

Lines 786 - 808 are the lines of interest. They basically set all the methods of that private instance of random to variables so they can be called this way.

From the docs.

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the random.Random class. You can instantiate your own instances of Random to get generators that don’t share state.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html